# Get last value with delta from previous row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data

```
| account | type | position | created_date |
|---------|------|----------|------|
|  1 | 1 | 1 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 1 | 2 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00 |
|  1 | 2 | 2 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 2 | 1 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00 |
|  1 | 1 | 2 | 2016-08-02 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 1 | 1 | 2016-08-02 00:00:00 |
|  1 | 2 | 1 | 2016-08-03 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 2 | 2 | 2016-08-03 00:00:00 |
|  1 | 1 | 2 | 2016-08-04 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 1 | 1 | 2016-08-04 00:00:00 |
|  1 | 2 | 2 | 2016-08-07 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 2 | 1 | 2016-08-07 00:00:00 |
```

I need to get last positions (account, type, position) and `delta` from previous position. I'm trying to use Window functions but only get all rows and can't grouping them/get last.

```sql
SELECT
    account,
    type,
    FIRST_VALUE(position) OVER w AS position,
    FIRST_VALUE(position) OVER w - LEAD(position, 1, 0) OVER w AS delta,
    created_date
FROM table
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY created_date DESC)
```

I have result

```
| account | type | position | delta | created_date |
|---------|------|----------|-------|--------------|
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2016-08-02 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2016-08-04 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | -1 | 2016-08-03 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2016-08-07 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2016-08-01 00:00:00 |
| and so on |
```

but i need only last record for each account/type pair

```
| account | type | position | delta | created_date |
|---------|------|----------|-------|--------------|
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2016-08-04 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2016-08-07 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2016-08-04 00:00:00 |
| and so on |
```

Sorry for my bad language and Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: If i use `GROUP BY account, type` then i get an error `column "position" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.
As i know, first (inside window function) i need an aggregate function. But i don't realy need to aggregate my positions.

Answer (score 0):

My "best" try..

```sql
WITH cte_delta AS (
    SELECT
        account,
        type,
        FIRST_VALUE(position) OVER w AS position,
        FIRST_VALUE(position) OVER w - LEAD(position, 1, 0) OVER w AS delta,
        created_date
    FROM table
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY created_date DESC)
),
cte_date AS (
    SELECT
        account,
        type,
        MAX(created_date) AS created_date
    FROM cte_delta
    GROUP BY account, type
)
SELECT cd.*
FROM
    cte_delta cd,
    cte_date ct
WHERE
    cd.account = ct.account
    AND cd.type = ct.type
    AND cd.created_date = ct.created_date
```